# Retrieve each product data from firebase cloud firestore - react-native

Tags: react-native

We're trying to retrieve product data from a specific category (from specific restaurant) but with the code below it is showing data duplicates; where every restaurant has the same products. Which is not what we want. Every restaurant has their own list of products.

We think the issue is in the path or our function is missing something (i,e: const cafesCollectionRef = collection(db, "cafes");

const productsCollectionRef = collection(db, "/cafes/dPyfv29lfsRqHemnChVo/products");

```
            useEffect(() => {
                const getProducts = async () => {
                const data = await getDocs(productsCollectionRef);
                setProducts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
                };
                getProducts();
            }, []);
```

Comment: Please embed the code snippet itself instead of an image.

Comment: The question is still not clear enough. Please try to explain the problem in other words and provide more code.

Comment: @YamanKATBY Ok let me elaborate. We have two collections on Firestore; a restaurant and product collection. For each restaurant we want to retrieve their product list. But now, all restaurants are showing the same exact products.

Comment: The problem is you are putting all products inside the same state by calling `setProducts` again and again.

Comment: @YamanKATBY so what is the ideal solution?

Comment: Create a cates state and keep all cafes inside it. Then map the cafes's array and fetch the products for each one of them and put the products inside the cate object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here's how we solved it: You have to specify the route of the object you're trying to retrieve that's inside the collection like this.

const productsCollectionRef = collection(db, "/cafes/"+cafeId+"/products");

*the plus is string interpolation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).